# Is permanent storage of video metadata against the YouTube Data API ToS?

Tags: caching, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

The [YouTube Data API ToS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms) says:

> Your API Client may employ session-based caching solely of YouTube API results, but You must use commercially reasonable efforts to cause Your API Client to update cached results upon any changes in video metadata. For example, if a video is removed from the YouTube service or made "private" by the video uploader, cached results shall be removed from Your cache. For the avoidance of doubt, Your API Client shall not be designed to cache YouTube audiovisual content.

The [YouTube Data API overview](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#etags) also says:

> Your application can cache API resources and their ETags. Then, when your application requests a stored resource again, it specifies the ETag associated with that resource. If the resource has changed, the API returns the modified resource and the ETag associated with that version of the resource. If the resource has not changed, the API returns an HTTP 304 response (Not Modified), which indicates that the resource has not changed. Your application can reduce latency and bandwidth usage by serving cached resources in this manner.

This does not mean that any time I wish to request a resource I must go back to the YouTube Data API, correct?

The only data from the API I'm interested in storing in my database is

- ETag
- Video id
- Duration
- Title

Is it okay for me to store these four items in my database (given I update the information reasonably regularly)?

I'm not interested in storing any portion of the actual video whatsoever. Just the metadata.

Comment: I also would like to know this